# What is the difference between the implementation of streams in Python compared to a list?

Tags: python, arrays, file, stream

This may read like a stupid question, but I am trying to learn the ins and outs of file handling in Python from the ground (IOBase) up.

What actually distinguishes between a stream and another container object?

My (admittedly limited) understanding of lists (or arrays in other languages) is that it's implemented as a contiguous block of memory, much like a string.

It seems like you can create a byte stream object with initial data like:

```
f = io.BytesIO(b"some test data")
```

This can then be read byte-by-byte. It looks like this is just a block of bytes that can be read or written like a string or array.

What actually makes a stream a stream?

I am interested both in the abstract concept as well as the implementation.

I know this may not be a well-defined question, but I am hoping someone can enlighten me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Although Streams are objects which resemble like Collections in the sense that they support Iteratable protocol, however, they are not meant for storing a logical set of complete data but rather a part of the data e.g. picking from a file, a network socket, a string or a web service, performing whatever operation that is required on that part of data and passing it back to the downstream which could again be a file, a network socket, a string or a web service etc. The intention is not to store the whole data like a list/array in the memory but only the part of data which is fetched by the Iterating Object using its set of methods (e.g. read, readline etc) from the Data source (e.g. a file) and passing it back to the Data Sink using methods e.g. write, writeline etc. The entire data still physically resides where the Data Source and Data Sink reside, only a part of the data that is fetched by Streaming Object methods resides in the memory of the machine where Python code is being executed.

A brief but concise definition of streams that answers your question (What actually makes a stream a stream?) is here in the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing)

A very good example of the File based stream object is here in the link: https://gawron.sdsu.edu/python_for_ss/course_core/book_draft/anatomy/files.html

In addition to this, data need not be in text format as opposed to List/Arrays etc.

If you are looking more holistic details with implementations, here are more links:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#
https://docs.python.domainunion.de/3/library/asyncio-stream.html